# How Can I Configure Lumen To Broadcast Events via Pusher?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, pusher, laravel-broadcast

Lumen's docs state that "Lumen supports several broadcast drivers out of the box: `Pusher`, `Redis`, and a `log` driver for local development and debugging. A configuration example is included for each of these drivers. The `BROADCAST_DRIVER` configuration option may be used to set the default driver."

In my .env file I have set `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`. Where/how can I configure my pusher ID, key, and secret? I see that in Laravel a configuration file for setting these options lies within `config/broadcasting.php`. **Where can I set these options within Lumen?**

Temporarily I have edited `Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager` and hard coded my values in.

```
protected function createPusherDriver(array $config)
    {
        // override
        $app_id = 'hidden';
        $key = 'hidden';
        $secret = 'hidden';

        return new PusherBroadcaster(
            new Pusher($key, $secret, $app_id, Arr::get($config, 'options', []))
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Essentially you have to add in the config files yourself.

1. Create a `config` directory in the root of your app.
2. Copy `config/broadcasting.php` from a working laravel installation into this directory
3. Add the following keys to your `.env` file: `PUSHER_SECRET, PUSHER_KEY, PUSHER_APP_ID`

Answer (score 4):

In general, Lumen supports two modes of configuration:

- Setting environment variables consumed by Lumen's [internal config files](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/tree/5.5/config)
- Creating project config files that override Lumen's internal configuration

Lumen provides environment-based configuration variables needed to configure most of the framework's components, including Pusher. Though unclear from the docs, we can also configure Lumen through config files like Laravel. This enables advanced configuration that Lumen may not support through its built-in configuration structure.

By default, new Lumen projects don't provide configuration files like new Laravel projects do in the *config/* directory. As @Feek discovered, we can create the *config/* directory and add any needed config files. For example, we can create the *config/broadcasting.php* file to set up broadcast connections.

When creating a config file in the project like this, Lumen will automatically read configuration values from the file if it matches the name of one of the Lumen built-in config files. If we want to add a custom configuration file that doesn't match one of Lumen's internal config filenames, we need to manually instruct Lumen to read the config file in a service provider or in *bootstrap/app.php*.

For instance, to load configuration values from *config/my-custom-config.php*, add this line to the application's boot process:

```
$app->configure('my-custom-config');
```

In the particular case of this question, Lumen's built-in *broadcasting.php* config file reads Pusher environment variables for us, so we don't need to create a config file in the project for these. Simply set the `BROADCAST_DRIVER`, `PUSHER_SECRET`, `PUSHER_KEY`, and `PUSHER_APP_ID` in *.env*.